# How can I delay the mouseout function?

Tags: jquery, timeout

I have this code:

```
 var shortcuts = $('#geo_shortcuts');
    shortcuts.find('li').hoverIntent(
        function () {
            // Open the Panel
            $(this).find('.geo_shortcuts_content').stop().animate({
                top: '-122'
            }, 300);
        },
        function () {
            //Close de Panel
            $(this).find('.geo_shortcuts_content').stop().animate({
                top: '0'
            }, 400);
        }
    );
```

How can I do to only allow the Close panel after 2 seconds of mouseout? I know I should do a settimeout function but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method:

```
$(this).find('.geo_shortcuts_content').stop().delay(2000).animate({
    top: '0'
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to do that

```
hideDelayTimer = null;
    shortcuts.find('li').hoverIntent(
        function () {
            // Open the Panel
            clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
            $(this).find('.geo_shortcuts_content').stop().animate({
                top: '-122'
            }, 300);
        },
    function () {
        //Close de Panel
        clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
        hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            hideDelayTimer = null;
                $(this).find('.geo_shortcuts_content').stop().animate({
                    top: '0'
                }, 400);
        }, 2000);
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Always happy to help. Can you close the topic using green tick?